# Using .netrc with SourceForge and Git

Tags: git, sourceforge

I know, this seems like a beginner question, but it's not. I'm using .netrc file with all the Git repositories successfully, except for the ones on SourceForge.

I can't seem to find anything in SF Documentation either.

I'm basically adding these lines to my .netrc, but it still asks for my password:

```
 machine git.code.sf.net
 login xxxxx
 password xxxxx

 machine api.git.code.sf.net
 login xxxxx
 password xxxxx
```

I tried all other variations I can think of, but I can't make it work. Is there anyone out there that has done this? And how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and add the protocol as well in that .netrc file (considering the [Git HTTPS URL for SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Git/) is `https://<USERNAME>@git.code.sf.net/p/PROJECTNAME/MOUNTPOINT`):

```
machine git.code.sf.net
login <USERNAME>
password xxxxx
protocol https
```

And see if the issue persists.

Make sure the URL returned by `git remote -v` (for the remote 'origin') does include your login:

```
git remote set-url origin https://<USERNAME>@git.code.sf.net/p/PROJECTNAME/MOUNTPOINT
                                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

If it does not work, try and set `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE`, in order to have more information (as [in this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/8608/)).

---

It turned out the [OP purplehuman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4516901/purplehuman) was using an SSH URL instead of an HTTPS one.

As I [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456241/anybody-using-netrc-with-sourceforge-and-git/28456415?noredirect=1#comment45239902_28456415):

> 1. SourceForge uses SSH or HTTPS for read/write access.
> 2. If you are using SSH, then I confirm that `.netrc` is *not* involved in any way: it is used only for providing username/password for a HTTPS URL, not for the SSH passphrase.
>      For the SSH passphrase, (assuming your private SSH key is protected by a passphrase), you would need an `ssh-agent`, not a `.netrc` file.

To switch to HTTPS:

```
git remote set-url origin https://<USERNAME>@git.code.sf.net/p/PROJECTNAME/MOUNTPOINT
```

*Then* the `.netrc` file would be used (by `curl` within the `git push`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually sourceforge uses ssh as the protocol for rw access. Do you have any suggestion regarding that? Unfortunately `protocol https` doesn't work, and my origin url includes my username.

Comment: @purplehuman Two things: 1/ sourceforge uses ssh *or* https for read/write access. 2/ If you are using ssh, then I confirm that `.netrc` is *not* involved in any way: it is used only for providing username/password for https url, not for ssh passphrase. For ssh passphrase, (supposing your private ssh key is protected by a passphrase), you would need an ssh-agent, not a `.netrc` file.

Comment: @purplehuman so if you want to use a `.netrc`, use the `git remote set-url` command I mention in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, you were right. It was my stupid mistake.

Comment: It kinda WAS a beginner question then.

Comment: @purplehuman no problem. I have included the actual issue in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks again. I hope this question and your answer helps someone.

Comment: @purplehuman that was the idea behind my edit indeed. I used to make that same mistake myself ;)